# Use old style UI when editing object CRUD in a permission set

Tags: permission-sets, ui

Is there a way to use the old profile UI when editing a permission set?  I'm trying to build a workaround for today's massive permissions crash in Salesforce.  I want to set CRUD permissions on a lot of objects, and the new UI makes you do it one by one.

When I set the old UI for profiles, this is what I get.  This is exactly what I want to see for permission set objects also:

[image]

But when I go to the permission set objects, I still get the new UI:
[image]

Comment: This is really annoying. We would've think that disabling "Enhanced Profile User Interface" (Under Setup -> User Management Settings) would affect the Permission Set's page layout (like it does for Profiles), but it doesn't :(